# CentOS 6.4 Network interfaces fail when rebooting and must be started manually

Tags: networking, centos6.4

Hi Im having a strange issue that seems to be plaguing all 3 of my HP ProLiant DL360 servers that are all running an identical configuration of CentOS 6.4.

It seems that when the network daemon is restarted (or just started when it was not) it fails when it attempts to bring up the interface, eth0 in this example. however when I issue ifup eth0 it takes 2 seconds and then its working like it should. The exact output is as follows.

```
 
[root@Hostname1 ~]# service network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:            [ OK ]
Shutting down loopback interface:        [ OK ]
Bringing up loopback interface:          [ OK ]
Bringing up interface eth0:
Determining IP information for eth0... failed; no link present. Check cable?

[root@Hostname1 ~]# ifup eth0

Determining IP Information for  eth0... done.
```

I have no idea why this happens, and it only happens some of the time. I do have the interface set to start on boot as well as checked the cables. I'm at a loss, any help would be nice, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

~ Mikka

Comment: Could you show content of the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 ?

Comment: @ALex_hha aye, Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your network switch has a delay in between the switchport coming up and registering link.

Try adding something like `LINKDELAY=5` to your `ifcfg-eth0` file, then reboot.

Increase or decrease the delay as required, try with a few values from 1 to 31.